# Filling a list with classes which text point to a class

Tags: c#, polymorphism

How can I reduce this _tile assignment, so I could make a single assignment?

x is a anonymous list.

```
x => List {String name, int x, int y}
```

and a List _tiles

```
_tiles.AddRange(from tile in x
where tile.Type.ToLower() == "start".ToLower()
select new Start(this)
{
Position = new Vector2(tile.X, tile.Y),
Texture = _texture2D

});

_tiles.AddRange(from tile in x
where tile.Type.ToLower() == "One".ToLower()
select new OneTouch(this)
{
Position = new Vector2(tile.X, tile.Y),
Texture = _texture2D

});
```

...

```
_tiles.AddRange(from tile in x
where tile.Type.ToLower() == "Two".ToLower()
select new ReverseTouch(this)
{
Position = new Vector2(tile.X, tile.Y),
Texture = _texture2D
```

Comment: Do Start, OneTouch and ReverseTouch inherit from a common ancestor?

Comment: Yeah, they all inherit from Tile class

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable<Tile> tiles = x.Select(tile =>
{
  Tile currentTile = null;

  switch (tile.Type.ToLower())
  {
    case "start":
      currentTile = new Start(this);
      break;

    case "One":
      currentTile = new OneTouch(this);
      break;

    case "Two":
      currentTile = new Start(this)
      break;

    ...

    default:
      // You know what to do...
   }

   currentTile.Position = new Vector2(tile.X, tile.Y),
   currentTile.Texture = _texture2D

   return currentTile;
});
```

From there you can build a list using `tiles.ToList()`
or fill an existing one using `_tiles.AddRange(tiles);`

Comment: So there is no easy way that I could use a Dictionary<string,Type> for this?

Comment: Yes there is but it's a different question...  x.GroupBy(tile => tile.Type.ToLower()) will group your entities by type